# MINIX 3 as a dns-server?

Tags: c, web-services

Is is it possible to have Minix 3 as a dns-server and if one would dare to code the service self how would that code look like (roughly)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minix actually has a nameserver in it already. Since Minix is open source, you can use it as a starting point.  The program is called "nonamed". The man page says it isn't a name daemon, but actually it is.

It's just that it's very simple, which is probably what you want. Either you can use it as is, just put all hostnames you want to resolve in /etc/hosts, and "nonamed" will export those...  or use nonamed as something to extend upon. At least the protocol is there already.

Man page for [nonamed](http://www.minix3.org/manpages/man8/nonamed.8.html)(8) and [source code](https://gforge.cs.vu.nl/gf/project/minix/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcommands%2Fnonamed%2Fnonamed.c&view=log).

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of a big question for little, ol' StackOverflow.  I'd suggest looking around for [some code](https://www.isc.org/downloadables/11) that you could use or port.